# How to setup a network printer with authentication and Windows support in Ubuntu Server 19.04?

Tags: server, printing

I've got a headless Ubuntu 19.04 server and a HP DeskJet 2545 connected through USB. I'm trying to setup a printer server to allow printing from my Windows laptop and Android smartphone. Additionally, I'd like to secure it with a password.

Could anyone tell me how to do this "the right way"?

So far, I've installed CUPS and HPLIP, logged into the web interface, added the printer using the HPLIP driver, and managed to print a test page, but from there I'm lost.